# Jenkins does not trigger when commits are pushed to Stash

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins does not trigger when I push a commit to a repo on Stash. When I press the Trigger Jenkins button in the Stash Webhook, then Jenkins starts building but not automatically once a commit enters. I have gone through some material and made the necessary settings in both Stash and Jenkins. Is there a place to start debugging whats going on after I make the push to Stash? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I shall give those new plugins a try. But is there someone else who has set up the system trying to trigger Jenkins by pushing to stack? And if it works could you tell me how you have configured the system? My Stash repo contains only one master branch and I am tracking that branch on Jenkins. I have confirmed that the repo URL's match on both sides and in the branch column i have given as refs/heads/master. Also is there a way to check the notifyCommit POST request or something going from Stash to Jenkins? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Webhook plugin in my CI environment, but I stopped using it.

I don't know how to debug this plugin but here is the solution I'm using right now.

To trigger a Jenkins job on Stash commits, I'm using this free plugin:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.aeffle.stash.plugin.stash-http-get-post-receive-hook/server/overview

You can configure it in the Settings/Hooks section:

[image]

[image]

You can use the filters if you want to trigger different jobs for the same Git repo.

If you want to have a build button in Stash, you can also use this plugin:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/se.bjurr.prnfs.pull-request-notifier-for-stash/server/overview

[image]